# Changing dates in different time zones by adding to POSIXlt

Tags: r

I am running into an error when I try to localize times for "date" (a variable of class=POSIXlt) in my dataset.  Example code is as follows:

```
# All dates are coded by survey software in EST(not local time)
date <- c("2011-07-26 07:23", "2011-07-29 07:34", "2011-07-29 07:40")
region <-c("USA-EST", "UK", "Singapore")

#Change the times based on time-zone differences
start_time<-strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %h:%m")
localtime=as.POSIXlt(start_time)
localtime<-ifelse(region=="UK",start_time+6,start_time)
localtime<-ifelse(region=="Singapore",start_time+12,start_time)

#Then, I need to extract the hour and weekday
weekday<-weekdays(localtime)
hour<-factor(localtime)
```

There must be something wrong with my `"ifelse"` statement, because I get the error: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. Please help!

Comment: Your `strptime` should be `start_time<-strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s")`

Comment: Hi there-sorry about that.  Edited to actually reflect my data. I don't *think* strptime is the problem...

Comment: Your `date` is not formatted like that.  Notice that `start_time` is `NA NA NA`.  Use a format like `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` instead of `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M`

Comment: Made those changes (although I can apparently read the dates in using my incorrect code). Again, I don't think strptime is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about using R's native time code? The trick is that you can't have more than one time-zone in a POSIX vector, so use a list instead:

```
region <- c("EST","Europe/London","Asia/Singapore")
(localtime <- lapply(seq(date),function(x) as.POSIXlt(date[x],tz=region[x])))
[[1]]
[1] "2011-07-26 07:23:00 EST"

[[2]]
[1] "2011-07-29 07:34:00 Europe/London"

[[3]]
[1] "2011-07-29 07:40:00 Asia/Singapore"
```

And to convert to a vector in a single timezone:

```
Reduce("c",localtime)
[1] "2011-07-26 13:23:00 BST" "2011-07-29 07:34:00 BST"
[3] "2011-07-29 00:40:00 BST"
```

Note that my system timezone is BST, but if yours is EST it will convert to that.

Comment: Hi there-I follow your logic, but am having trouble applying it to my real code.  I get the error: `Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(start_time[x], tz = timezone[x]) : 'origin' must be supplied`.  Thoughts?

Comment: @roody It sounds like you are passing numbers rather than character strings to `as.POSIXlt`. Possibly because you have a factor rather than a character vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timezone handling built in in `POSIXct`:

```
> start_time <- as.POSIXct(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "America/New_York")
> start_time
[1] "2011-07-26 07:23:00 EDT" "2011-07-29 07:34:00 EDT" "2011-07-29 07:40:00 EDT"
> format(start_time, tz="Europe/London", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2011-07-26 12:23:00 BST" "2011-07-29 12:34:00 BST" "2011-07-29 12:40:00 BST"
> format(start_time, tz="Asia/Singapore", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2011-07-26 19:23:00 SGT" "2011-07-29 19:34:00 SGT" "2011-07-29 19:40:00 SGT"
```